# Не могу разобраться в иерархии androidX и Jetpack :P

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack-compose

Изучаю Android второй год, и сейчас окончательно запутался в иерархии библиотек AndroidX. Конкретизируя: Мы имеем библиотеки AndroidX, Jetpack и Jetpack Compose. Как они взаимосвязаны? В Jetpack Compose я видел пакеты из AndroidX и наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала разберемся, что есть что:

> **AndroidX** — это значительно усовершенствованная библиотека поддержки
> Android, исходная версия которой больше не поддерживается. Пакеты
> AndroidX полностью заменяют библиотеку поддержки Android, обеспечивая
> равенство функций и предоставляя новые библиотеки, которые можно
> использовать в приложениях Android.

> **Jetpack** включает в себя набор библиотек Android, которые включают в
> себя лучшие практики и обеспечивают обратную совместимость в ваших
> приложениях Android. Библиотеки Jetpack публикуются в пространстве имен AndroidX.

> **Jetpack Compose** представляет современный тулкит от компании Google для создания приложений под ОС Android на языке программирования
> Kotlin. Является частью экосистемы Jetpack.

Далее обратимся к [FAQ AndroidX](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:docs/faq.md):

> Как `androidx` и AndroidX связан с Jetpack? **Все они одно и то же!** Одним
> словом, `androidx` - это упаковка, а AndroidX - это рабочий процесс
> разработки для всех компонентов Jetpack. Jetpack - это внешний вид
> библиотек в `androidx`.
>
> Более подробно, Jetpack - это внешний бренд для набора компонентов,
> инструментов и руководств, которые улучшают работу разработчиков на
> Android. AndroidX - это проект разработки с открытым исходным кодом,
> который определяет политику рабочего процесса, управления версиями и
> выпуска для ВСЕХ библиотек, включенных в Jetpack. Все библиотеки в
> пакете Java для `androidx` соответствуют единому набору руководящих
> принципов разработки API, соответствуют циклам версий SemVer и альфа /
> бета-версий и используют средство отслеживания ошибок Android для
> обнаружения ошибок и запросов функций.

Если кратко, то иерархия, как я понимаю, такая:
**AndroidX -> Jetpack -> Jetpack Compose**.
То есть AndroidX это просто набор библиотек, которые пришли на смену старой Support Library. Некоторые из этих библиотек объединили в экосистему Jetpack. Jetpack Compose - одна из библиотек семейства Jetpack.